# React onChange rerender dynamic input fields strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When changing data in dynamic fields, my functional component copies the current field and redraws the field and adds it to the end of the form. I displayed input fields via Object.keys.map and put there state and check type with switch, after display text, number, checkbox fields together.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Form = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    companyName: "seenus",
    tradeName: "ТОРТАЙ О.А ИП",
    description: "",
    email: "olzhastortay@gmail.com",
    region: "Almaty",
    phone: "(707) 795-15-09",
    bin: "",
    code: "",
    isActive: true,
    merchant_terminal: {
      terminal_id: "98264471",
      saveCard: false,
      isActive: true,
      currencyName: "KZT",
      isAmexAllowed: false,
      sendBack: false,
      parentId: "",
      B64ENCODE: false,
      persLimit: 0,
      isRecurAllowed: false,
      shouldUseNewKey: true,
      minSum: 0,
      postlinkTries: 0,
      MCC: 0,
      dailyLimit: 0,
      isFromEpay1: false,
      permitted_countries: "",
      forbidden_countries: ""
    }
  })

  
  const iterate = (obj: any): any => {
    
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {

      switch(typeof obj[key]) {
        case 'object': 
          return iterate(obj[key])

        case 'string': 

          return (
            <div className="section-form" key={key}>
                <TextField 
                  label={key} 
                  variant="outlined"
                  defaultValue={obj[key]}
                  onChange={handleChange(key)}
                />
            </div>
          )

        case 'number': 
        
          return (
            <div className="section-form" key={key}>
                <TextField 
                  label={key} 
                  variant="outlined" 
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={obj[key]}
                  onChange={handleChange(key)}
                />
            </div>
          )

        case 'boolean': 
        
          console.log('boolean inside')
          return (
            <div className="section-form" key={key}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Switch checked={obj[key]} onChange={handleChange(key)} />}
                label={key}
              />
            </div>
          )

      }

    })

  }


  const handleChange = (prop: any) => (event: any) => {
    
    const {checked, value, type} = event.target
    
    switch (type) {
      case 'checkbox':
        return setState((prev: any) => ({...prev, [prop]: checked}))
      default: 
        return setState((prev: any) => ({...prev, [prop]: value}))
    }

  }

  return (
    <form>
      <h1 className="merch-title">Страница нового коммерсанта</h1>
      <div className="merch-form">
        { iterate(state) }
      </div>
      <div className="merch-btn">
        <Button size="large" variant="contained" type="submit" color="primary">
            создать коммерсанта
        </Button>
      </div>
      
    </form>
  )

}

export default Form
```

[input fields IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5sw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleChange = (arr?: any) => (event: any) => {
    
        const {checked, value, type} = event.target
    
        let tmp = state
        const depth = arr.length -1
        
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          const depthKey = arr[i]
          
          if(i < depth) {
            tmp = tmp[depthKey]
          }
          if(i === depth) {
            tmp[depthKey] = (type === 'checkbox') ? checked : value
          }
    
        }
    
        return setState({...state})
    
      }
```

The problem was in state. Every time when I returned state with nested object, I was returing first depth of object.